# BIRT report: dynamically adding columns to a table based on dataset data

Tags: report, birt

In my report, a table is displaying results from a dataset and it has 6 columns.

But sometimes the dataset returns more than 6 columns depending on the report parameters.

So I need a way to dynamically add columns to my table

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it the other way round.

The number of the columns in the query is fixed anyway (for example: FIXED_A, FIXED_B, DYNCOL01, ..., DYNCOL20).

In the layout, your table should have columns for all columns (FIXED_A to DYN_COL20).

Clear the table's width. Set a fixed width for the fixed columns (with enough room left for the dynamic columns). Clear the width of all dynamic columns.

From now on, do not resize and column with the mouse, because this would set individual widths for each column again.

In your table properties, add aggregate bindings for each DYN_COLnn using the MAXIMUM function (let's call these MAX_COL01, ..., MAX_COL20).

For each columns, use a visibility expression like this (the number matching the layout column to the query column accordingly), e.g. for the first dynamic column:

!!row["MAX_COL01"]]

The !! means basically: interprete this as boolean, so the result is: show this column only if MAX_COL01 is not null - or in other words: if DYN_COL1 is not empty in any of the rows.